# Web Server Synchronization

Tags: iis, synchronization, load-balancing

I'm having 2 identical webservers(running IIS) which i intend to load balance with Hardware Based Application Load Balancer. I need a Synchronization software to do real-time sync of the data between the 2 servers. Any suggestions for a good sync app to accomplish the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Web Farm Framework, or the Web Deployment Tool.

http://www.iis.net/download/webfarmframework

http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy

WFF automatically synchronizes, but requires a controller machine to do this. Web Deploy can script site/content/settings syncs.

Comment: Thanks Tristan for sharing the links. I'll try with the WebDeploy & see whether it fits into my setup.

Answer (score 0):

You best bet is to use the built in windows functionality DRS which allows you to replicate shares/folders between two or more machines in real time.

Comment: can u provide any links for the DRS ? I also want to know whether there will be any over head while using the in-built Functionality of Windows for Real-time sync

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Replication_Service is a good start. There will of course be an overhead but its usually quite small with DRS as it monitors files and folders for writes rather than constantly reading all files looking for changes. It does require some RAM (depending on folder size) to hold its replication state and information within however.

Comment: I think that File Replication Service has been replaced by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_File_System_(Microsoft) but beware that solution is probably not safe with virtual machines or restoring from full backups as per  http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2013/04/05/safely-virtualizing-dfsr.aspx